# How to determine privacy status of Facebook post using graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook graph API version 2.0 in Node, via the fbgraph module.

I'm posting to a user's feed with the token they've authorized. While authorizing, they are able to choose what privacy level my app will be posting at, by default.

Ideally, I'd love to know what privacy level the message was posted at in the response from Facebook from the posting process. But there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

So now I'm trying to use the Graph API to request details on the newly posted message, to determine it's privacy level. [In their docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post), they show a "privacy" field that should come back, with all of these details. But when I actually use their Graph Explorer tool to test this out, I never get back that field. If I explicitly request the privacy field in my call, it says it doesn't know what that is. "(#100) Unknown fields: privacy."

By default I'm getting back: id, from, message, updated_time, and likes.

How are we to find out the privacy level of a post on Facebook?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible. Any stories published via your app using the API automatically inherit the privacy settings the user provided when logging in. I'd imagine that FB specifically didn't provide this in their API design.

Comment: @ChrisHoughton I can understand not letting the app change the privacy setting, but why not let the app know what choice the user has made? And if that's true, why not detail this huge caveat in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post  Also, seems weird because in the case I'm testing on, the post in question is actually public. So why can't the app itself see this privacy level? Especially since the API docs imply it should be available.

Comment: My bad, I think this is a bug on Facebook's end. Based on the docs it @mason-g-zhwiti definitely should be possible. I'd recommend filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/